# API authentication with a single ID

Tags: security, rest, api, api-design, web-api

A typical API authentication usually rely on a pair of API ID + SECRET, my question is: if the API ID is unique and randomly generated and is considered strong enough (e.g. SHA512), why a SECRET is even needed?

What if, I created an API only need a API ID for authentication, what would be the drawback, especially in term of security?

Some people might say, it is easy to revoke the SECRET without changing API ID, **but this does not sound since if you need to update the SECRET, you need to modify the config/source code** as well.

Internally the API program can still have some unique ID to identify the client, **but this information does not need to expose to the client code**, just use a single ID is enough, right?

Actually I would considered using a single API ID is more secure - since when you change , it is more hard to identify the client (as there is no constant API ID)

Any conveats?

Answer (score 2):

This is a lot like asking why we have both a username and a password for all our regular internet accounts, when arguably just a password is sufficient.

The first reason is actually contained in your question:

> Actually I would considered using a single API ID is more secure - since when you change , it is more hard to identify the client (as there is no constant API ID)

That's the problem. **Many services simply don't work if they can't remember who you are**. Imagine if an e-mail provider "lost" all e-mail you'd ever sent or received every time you changed your password. Nobody would ever use them.

The second reason is that it's not more secure. **Either way, the attacker only needs to figure out the secret** in order to impersonate you. The presence of a non-secret does not automatically make the secret any less secure (assuming the method used to generate the secret and non-secret is cryptographically secure).